# How to read and upload ByteArray image in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, flash, imagemagick, carrierwave

We are having Rails in backend and FLASH in frontend.

We wanted to upload image but we don't have any physical image we have pixes in ByteArray.

Now We want to upload that  ByteArray(image) into rails through API.

How can we read that ByteArray image and convert into original image and upload to rails server. For image upload we are using carrierwave gem and rmagic in server.

Sample ByteArray image:

> xÚ_@ ¿PNG 
>   IHDR,,y}u¼4IDATxÚì½i$Iv-ûæ¾{¸Ǿ瞕UUµu÷$úÄm8CÎÎ
>   x¾ëWêHzOo¶ޗ!G

Answer (score 0):

```
# arr is ByteArray. 'image' is still in memory
image = Magick::Image.constitute(width, height, "RGB", arr.flatten)
```